# Inserting duplicates and non duplicates in different columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data and I hope you help me as I could not find my solution in stack overflow.

```html
ID Code
1 A
1 A12
2 M
3 A
2 M12
4 A12
5 M12
6 M
7 A
6 M12
```

As you can see  some IDs are duplicated and some not. I  want to generate some columns to see  each code in a specific column. The desirable outcome is :

```html
ID Code A1 A121 M1 M121
1 A A N/A N/A N/A
1 A12 N/A A12 N/A N/A
2 M N/A N/A M N/A
3 A A N/A N/A N/A
2 M12 N/A N/A N/A M12
4 A12 N/A A12 N/A N/A
5 M12 N/A N/A N/A M12
6 M N/A N/A M N/A
7 A A N/A N/A N/A
6 M12 N/A N/A N/A M12
```

I understand you want me to show my attempts. Unfortunately, I was unable to do it as a novice. Very much appreciated for your help.

Comment: 1. You seem to be bothered by some IDs showing up multiple times, but your desired outcome doesn't resolve this. Can you clarify if this is an issue or whether you actually prefer to have only a single row per ID? 2. I don't understand how the column labels come to be. Why is the first column called A1, rather than just A? It seems that the column name is a concatentation of the Code and '1'.

Comment: Thank you @ FlorianBrezina,  I want to have a single row per ID.

Comment: For the given sample data and the expected output you could do `library(reshape2); dcast(dat, ID + Code ~ paste0(Code, "1"))`, where `dat` is the name of your dataframe. If you don't the the suffix "1" simply do `dcast(dat, ID + Code ~ Code)`

Comment: Thank you @ FlorianBrezina, No reason for the name of columns, just wanted to show for example  column A only get As and so on.. A is Ok ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The it should be just

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~ID, ~Code,
              1, "A",
              1, "A12",
              2, "M",
              3, "A",
              2, "M12",
              4, "A12",
              5, "M12",
              6, "M",
              7, "A",
              6, "M12")

df %>%
  spread(key = Code, value = Code)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
     ID A     A12   M     M12  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     A12   NA    NA   
2     2 NA    NA    M     M12  
3     3 A     NA    NA    NA   
4     4 NA    A12   NA    NA   
5     5 NA    NA    NA    M12  
6     6 NA    NA    M     M12  
7     7 A     NA    NA    NA
```

Many would prefer a 1/0 encoding of the columns, then the solution is

```
df %>%
 mutate(bin = 1) %>%
 spread(key = Code, value = bin, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 7 x 5
     ID     A   A12     M   M12
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     0     0
2     2     0     0     1     1
3     3     1     0     0     0
4     4     0     1     0     0
5     5     0     0     0     1
6     6     0     0     1     1
7     7     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: I really appreciate  for your great help. All solutions are great.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can spread the `Code` column out like this:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(id_temp = row_number(), code_temp = Code) %>%
    spread(code_temp, code_temp) %>%
    select(-id_temp)

#    ID Code    A  A12    M  M12
# 1   1    A    A <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2   1  A12 <NA>  A12 <NA> <NA>
# 3   2    M <NA> <NA>    M <NA>
# 4   2  M12 <NA> <NA> <NA>  M12
# 5   3    A    A <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 6   4  A12 <NA>  A12 <NA> <NA>
# 7   5  M12 <NA> <NA> <NA>  M12
# 8   6    M <NA> <NA>    M <NA>
# 9   6  M12 <NA> <NA> <NA>  M12
# 10  7    A    A <NA> <NA> <NA>
```